# Invoked with 0.7 when i'm running a python code to track fingers

Tags: python

this is the code im working on

```
import cvzone
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
detector = cvzone.HandDetector(maxHands=1, detectionCon=0.7)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

and im getting this error

```
TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.7

Process finished with exit code 1
```

im trying to track my fingers using the opencv libs and my camera isnt running when m running this code

Comment: Looks like `detection_con` has to be an `int`. Did you read the docs?

Comment: I solved the problem, it wasnt about the detectioncon, I had to change the mediapipe version to 0.8.8 and it worked, thank you for your contribution